# Method to sum of the elements of different sized matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, dimension

Can anybody help me to find out the method to sum of the elements of different sized matrix in **Matlab** ?

Let say that I have 2 matrices with numbers.
Example:

```
A=[1 2 3;
   4 5 6;
   7 8 9]

B=[10 20 30;
   40 50 60]
```

I wanna create matrix **C** filling with sum(absolute subtract of matrix A and B).

**Example in MS Excel.**
[image]

D10=ABS(D3-I3)+ABS(E3-J3)+ABS(F3-K3)

E10=ABS(D4-I3)+ABS(E4-J3)+ABS(F4-K3)

F10=ABS(D5-I3)+ABS(E5-J3)+ABS(F5-K3)

And then (Like above)

D11=ABS(D3-I4)+ABS(E3-J4)+ABS(F3-K4)

E11=ABS(D4-I4)+ABS(E4-J4)+ABS(F4-K4)

F11=ABS(D5-I4)+ABS(E5-J4)+ABS(F5-K4)

***Actually A is a 30x8 matrix and B is a 10x8 matrix.***

How can i write this in Matlab?

Comment: I think you can edit your matrices like this - `A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9], B=[10 20 30; 40 50 60]`

Comment: Thanks,Great function.Worked.
But **Actually A is a 30x8 matrix and B is a 10x8 matrix.**
Please help me.

Comment: Tried the answer provided here for the bigger case?

Comment: Thanks!Again.This function also worked for the bigger case.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%%// Spread out B to the third dimension so that the singleton
%%// second dimension thus created could be used with bsxfun for expansion in
%%// that dimension
t1 = permute(B,[3 2 1])

%%// Perform row-wise subtraction and then summing of their absolute values
%%// as needed
t2 = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,t1)),2)

%%// Since the expansion resulted in data in third dimension, we need to 
%%// squeeze it back to a 2D data
out = squeeze(t2)'
```

Comment: Can u explain this expression?
Especially **squeeze,permute(B,[3 2 1]),2).**

Comment: @user3455066 Please try to follow the comments added along with the codes as edits.